# Python app runs successfully on local machine but gives error "Internal Server Error" when deployed to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I've written a pretty simple Python application using Pandas & Flask that looks like this:

```
import mimetypes
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory, send_file
import os


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/result', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def result():

    if request.method == "POST":

        pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
        pd.set_option('display.width', None)
        pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

        csv_file = request.files['file']
        filename = csv_file.filename
        csv_file.save(os.path.join("uploads", csv_file.filename))

        df1 = pd.DataFrame()

        df2 = pd.read_csv("./uploads/pipeline_export.csv")
        df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2])

        df1['Name'] = '=HYPERLINK(' '"' + df2['Profile URL'] + '"' + \
            ',' + '"' + df2['First Name'] + ' ' + df2['Last Name'] + '"' + ')'
        df1.insert(0, 'Full Name', df1['Name'])
        del df1['Last Name']
        del df1['First Name']
        del df1['Name']
        del df1['Profile URL']
        df1 = df1.fillna('')
        # df1.to_excel("C:\\Users\\Sam\\Desktop\\convertedexport.xlsx")
        # convertedFile = df1.to_excel("converted.xlsx")
        df1.to_excel(os.path.join("./downloads", "convertedFile.xlsx"))
        return send_file('./downloads/convertedFile.xlsx', as_attachment=True)
        # return redirect(url_for('index.html', filename=filename))
        # return render_template("/index.html")


@app.route("/uploads/<filename>")
def uploaded_file(filename):
    filename_processed = 'processed' + '-' + filename
    return send_from_directory("downloads", filename, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename=filename_processed)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The link to the repo can be found here: https://github.com/Web-Dev-Jr/TitusConvertPy

It works fine locally but when I deploy to Heroku I get the following error:

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Has anyone else run into something like this and could explain what my issue is?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [HTTP 500 (internal server error)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_server_errors) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. On Heroku, you can do this by running [`heroku logs`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-logs).

Comment: Though, at a glance it doesn't look like you're using the `PORT` environment variable. If that's true, your logs should confirm it.

Comment: Do you have `pandas` installed on your Heroku instance?

Comment: @TimRoberts I do have pandas installed. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the feedback Chris. I'll make sure to try and ask better questions as I get more familiar with it. I'm not familiar with using the PORT environment variable so I'll definitely start looking into that now. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify some of the  confusion here are the logs I get from Heroku:

Comment: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Using cached install of python-3.10.2
-----> Installing pip 21.3.1, setuptools 57.5.0 and wheel 0.37.0
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 120M
-----> Launching...
       Released v28

Comment: @WebDevJr, that's your _build_ log. I'm asking for your runtime logs, which you can see by running `heroku logs`. And please [edit] them into your question instead of posting a comment. As you can see, logs in comments are very hard to read.

Comment: do you have read and write permissions on the uploads folder on your server? To further debug, wrap the code in a try - except and log the error (if there is one) to a log file, or return the error with a 400 error code. This makes it easier to narrow things down.